# How to create a mobile layout for a component in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, responsive

I have a react code as shown below in which I want to create a separate mobile layout for a component in ReactJS. The following component below displays everything both in desktop and mobile view.

**React Code:**

```
const ProgramItem = (props) => {
    console.log(props);
    const [opened, setOpened] = useState(false);
    return(
       <div className={`program ${opened ? 'program--showContent' : 'program--hideContent'}`} onClick={(e) => {
          setOpened(!opened);
       }}>
            <div className="program-show-time">         

            </div>
            <div className="program-show-details">

            </div>  
       </div>
    )
}
```

What I want to achieve is I want to create a mobile-view layout inside that component so that I can write a separate CSS for that mobile-view layout.

**This is what I have tried:**

```
const ProgramItem = (props) => {
    console.log(props);
    const [opened, setOpened] = useState(false);
    const [openedMobile, setOpenedMobile] = useState(false);
    return(
         <div>
           <div className={`program ${opened ? 'program--showContent' : 'program--hideContent'}`} onClick={(e) => {
              setOpened(!opened);
           }}>
                <div className="program-show-time">         
    
                </div>
                <div className="program-show-details">
    
                </div>  
           </div>
        )
      }
       <div className={`program-mobile ${opened ? 'program--showContent--mobile' : 'program--hideContent--mobile'}`} onClick={(e) => {
          setOpened(!opened);
       }}>
            <div className="program-show-time">         

            </div>
            <div className="program-show-details">

            </div>  
       </div>
    </div>
    )
}
```

I am wondering if its the right way to create a separate mobile-view layout inside the component.

Comment: what does react-native have to do with this? that's not even react itself if that s just about layout. use css media queries and i am adding the css tag to you

Comment: [react-responsive](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-responsive) may be helpful

Answer (score 0):

While it's not a necessarily the worse solution, I would check window size instead of set classes and then render the elements I need.

```
let elementsToRender = <div> This is desktop </div>;
if (window.screen.width < 1000){ 
    elementsToRender = <div> This is mobile </div>
}

return(
elementsToRender
);
```